# Is it possible to show seconds in CakePHP time input?

Tags: cakephp, time, input, formhelper

I have the following field:
`$this->Form->input('vlog_in', array('timeFormat' => '24'));`

This is a 'time' field in database, so it formats the input like: 00:00 (hours:minutes).

How can i show the seconds select box, so my user can select it like 00:00:00 (hours:minutes:seconds)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just build out the form, then piece it together in the controller.  I know, not as pretty as if there were just a setting for it, but...

```
// VIEW
echo $this->Form->input('vlog_in_hours', array('type' => 'select',
    'options' => array_combine(range(0,23), range(0,23)),
));
echo $this->Form->input('vlog_in_minutes', array('type' => 'select',
    'options' => array_combine(range(0,59), range(0,59)),
));
echo $this->Form->input('vlog_in_seconds', array('type' => 'select',
    'options' => array_combine(range(0,59), range(0,59)),
));


//CONTROLLER
function whatever() {
    //...
    $data = $this->request->data['MyModel'];
    $time = $data['vlog_in_hours'].':'.$data['vlog_in_minutes'].':'.$data['vlog_in_seconds'];
    $this->request->data['MyModel']['vlog_in'] = $time;
    //...
    $this->MyModel->save($this->request->data);
    //...
}
```